# How to integral $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (z_0 + re^{i\theta})^j d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, Let $z_0 \in U$ and $r>0$ and assume $\{ z : |z-z_0|\leq r\}\subseteq U$, then how one can compute 
below 
without assuming cauchy integral formula? 
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (z_0 + re^{i\theta})^j d\theta \\
&\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{(z_0 + re^{i\theta})}^j d\theta
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Binomial theorem. Then a simple calcultion plus some algebraic manipulation will give you the result.

Basically the "main result" you need is:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i jt}dt=\frac{1}{ij}e^{ijt}\big|_0^{2\pi}=0,\quad j\neq 0$$
And $=2\pi$ if $j=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $C=\{z_0+re^{i\theta}\mid \theta\in [0,2\pi]\}$, your integrals are precisely $$-i\int_C \frac{z^j}{z-z_0}\mathrm d z\quad \text{and}\quad -i\int_C\frac{\overline{z}^j}{z-z_0}\mathrm d z.$$

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of showing this

(i) using Cauchy's integral formula [idea from @Surb]

Let $\gamma = \{z_0 + re^{i\theta} | \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}$, then 
\begin{align}
   &\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (z_0 + r e^{i\theta})^j d\theta =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{z^j}{z-z_0}dz = z_0^j \\
   & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \overline{(z_0+re^{i\theta})^j} d\theta = - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \overline{\frac{z^j}{z-z_0}} d\bar{z} = \bar{z}_0^j
\end{align}

(ii) Binomial expansion [idea comes from @b00n heT]

\begin{align}
 & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (z_0 + r e^{i\theta})^j d\theta = 
 \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} z_0^j \left(1+ j \frac{re^{i\theta}}{z_0} + \frac{j(j-1)}{2!} \frac{r^2 e^{2i\theta}}{z_0^2} + \cdots \right) d\theta =  z_0^j 
\end{align}
Since $j\neq 0$ and poisitve the last line holds.